# Subscribing to an entity without specifying attributes

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying to subscribe to an entity to get notifications using ONCHANGE.

The thing is that I'd like to get notified when new attributes get added or removed from the entity, otherwise said, I want a notification whenever anything changes on that entity.

Is that possible? I tried setting an empty condValues list in the query like this:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "case",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Case1"
        }
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
"Test Node 1"
 ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT5S"
}
```

But it didn't work.

PS: Note that I omitted the attributes Array to receive all the attributes on notification, this does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Orion version (0.19.0) doesn't implement such feature. However, it is planed to be done in the future (see [this issue at Orion github repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/350)).

**EDIT:** since Orion 0.27.0 you can subscribe to changes in any attribute. In order to do so, do the subscription omitting the `condValues` field (or use an empty array `[]` as value).

Comment: You can show your "support" to the feature adding a comment with "+1" in  the github issue (not only for this feature but for any other feature described in an Orion github issue).

Comment: How can we see when P6 is going to be in development? Is any public info regarding roadmap and dates?

Comment: Px labels are no longer used for "backlog" issues in GitHub (however, they are still in use for "bug" issues). What we are using now is the milestone field, with one or two milestone being scheduled in advance (current ongoing milestone is 0.21.0 and this feature has not yet been scheduled).

Comment: The feature will be finally included in Orion 0.27.0 (answer post has been edited in that way).